# "X et eux" ou "eux et X"?

Tags: pronoms, syntaxe, sujet

Si on a un sujet composé où une partie et un pronom au pluriel (par ex. *eux*) et l'autre un nom propre (par ex. *Jean*), on les prononce dans quel ordre? Voici un exemple:

- Jean parle.
- Ils parlent.

Combiné, on dit:

1. Jean et eux parlent. OU
2. Eux et Jean parlent.

Answer (score 2):

Dans le cas d'une combinaison avec *eux*: *Eux et Jean* n'est pas très heureux, peut-être parce qu'il y a deux voyelles en collision ou que ca sonne comme *eh euh*. Quelque chose cloche et instinctivement, je ne le dirais probablement pas. Même chose pour *Jean et eux*. Je me rabattrais plutôt sur *ils* en laissant le contexte aider à comprendre la composition du groupe. On pourrait essayer aussi quelque chose comme: *Avec Jean, ils parlent*, ou bien: *lui/Jean et ses amis parlent* ou en plus "lourd": *tous ensemble, y compris Jean, parlent* ou: *Jean se joint à ses amis pour parler*. Mais quelque chose ne va toujours pas très bien. Il faudrait retravailler la phrase dans son contexte. *Lui/Jean et ses amis ...* me semble le plus proche d'un flot naturel, mais encore une fois, il faudrait retravailler avec le contexte.

Answer (score 2):

> Ils parlent, Jean aussi.
> Eux parlent, ainsi que Jean.
> Jean parle, eux aussi.
> Lui et eux parlent.

Comment: On dirait que tu éprouves aussi un besoin d'utiliser autre chose que "_eh euh_", ou je me trompe? :-)

Comment: @Frank Je ne l'exclus pas mais c'est vrai que ça sonne mal dans *Jean et eux*.

Comment: Oui, on ne peut pas exclure, c'est pour ça que je disais dans ma réponse _n'est pas très heureux_.

Answer (score 1):

Grammaticalement parlant, il n'y a aucune différence entre les deux formulations, toutes deux correctes. Cependant, on préfèrera tout de même mettre "et eux" **après** "Jean". Cette préférence est une question de [politesse](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/guide/pronoms-personnels).

De la même manière, avec d'autres pronoms :

- "Alice et moi sommes sœurs."
- "L'alcool et toi, ça ne fait pas bon ménage."
- "Votre belle-mère et vous n'êtes jamais d'accord."
- "Ni nos alliés, ni nous ne sommes d'accord sur les termes de la convention."
- "Jean et eux parlent de politique."

Comment: D'accord avec la politesse, mais aucun de tes exemples n'utilise _et eux_ en particulier. Si tu devais en donner un avec _et eux_, que dirais-tu?

Comment: En effet, je fais ça de suite, merci Frank.

Comment: Pour moi, _et eux_ rappelle _eh euh_, et je n'aime pas trop. Je ne dis pas que c'est faux, mais je crois que je ne le dirais pas naturellement. Je chercherais instinctivement une autre construction ou une périphrase.

Answer (score -1):

Il n'y a pas d'ordre préféré, quelles que soient les combinaisons, nom et pronom ou pronom et pronom. On peut se rendre compte de cela en examinant ces deux pages d'exemples (les cas pertinents à la question sont rares en ce qui concerne les combinaisons "nom propre et pronom" et "pronom et nom propre".

- [eux et](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22eux%20et%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)
- [et eux](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22et+eux%22&lr=lang_fr&tbs=lr:lang_1fr&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AB5stBjtVhuQea13NVIKjLgrpm9saod7oA:1689031325417&ei=nZKsZPmKGbODi-gPwfC3-As&start=100&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwi5zamBpIWAAxWzwQIHHUH4Db8Q8tMDegQIaRAE&biw=1280&bih=662&dpr=1.5)